# Unable to register Kie Server with Kie Workbench

Tags: drools, kie, kie-workbench, drools-kie-server

"I'm setting up Kie Workbench 7.5 and Kie Server 7.5 both into tomcat 8.
But "Remote Servers" is showing blank list.

For installation reference I used http://blog.athico.com/2015/10/installing-kie-server-and-workbench-on.html this blog.

Once I hit http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server this URL I am getting expected output as below:

```
<response type="SUCCESS" msg="Kie Server info">
    <kie-server-info>
        <capabilities>KieServer</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BRM</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BPM</capabilities>
        <capabilities>CaseMgmt</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BPM-UI</capabilities>
        <capabilities>BRP</capabilities>
        <capabilities>DMN</capabilities>
        <capabilities>Swagger</capabilities>
        <location>
            http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server
        </location>
        <name>tomcat-kieserver</name>
        <id>tomcat-kieserver</id>
        <version>7.5.0.Final</version>
    </kie-server-info>
</response>
```

Configuration which I proviced

**1. setenv.bat**

```
set CATALINA_OPTS=-Xmx512M -Djbpm.tsr.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionSynchronizationRegistry -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.ds=java:comp/env/jdbc/jbpm -Djbpm.tm.jndi.lookup=java:comp/env/TransactionManager -Dorg.kie.server.persistence.tm=JBossTS -Dhibernate.connection.release_mode=after_transaction -Dorg.kie.server.id=tomcat-kieserver -Djava.security.auth.login.config=C:/softwares/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/webapps/kie-drools-wb/WEB-INF/classes/login.config -Dorg.kie.server.location=http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server -Dorg.kie.server.controller=http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/rest/controller -Dcom.arjuna.ats.jta.recovery.XAResourceRecovery1=com.arjuna.ats.internal.jdbc.recovery.BasicXARecovery;abs://C:/softwares/apache-tomcat-8.5.43/conf/xa-recovery-properties.xml
```

**2. server.xml**

```
<Valve className="org.kie.integration.tomcat.JACCValve" />
```

**3. context.xml**

```
<Resource name="sharedDataSource"
              auth="Container"
              type="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource"
              user="sa"
              password="sa"
              url="jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;MVCC=TRUE"
              description="H2 Data Source"
              loginTimeout="0"
              testOnBorrow="false"
              factory="org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSourceFactory"/>
```

**4. xa-recovery-properties.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
<properties>
    <entry key="DB_1_DatabaseUser">sa</entry>
    <entry key="DB_1_DatabasePassword">sa</entry>
    <entry key="DB_1_DatabaseDynamicClass"></entry>
    <entry key="DB_1_DatabaseURL">java:comp/env/h2DataSource</entry>
</properties>
```

On Tomcat console I am getting below warning:

```
WARNING [KieServer-ControllerConnect] org.kie.server.services.impl.controller.DefaultRestControllerImpl.connectToSingleController Exception encountered while syncing with controller at http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/rest/controller/server/tomcat-kieserver error Error while sending PUT request to http://localhost:8080/kie-drools-wb/rest/controller/server/tomcat-kieserver response code 401
```

Answer (score 1):

Workbench 7.0+ is not support Tomcat any more. If you want to use Workbench (it is already renamed to Business Central and has latest version 7.24) it should run on Wildfly 14.

You can try this quick start (just unzip file and it is ready to try or copy configurations): https://www.jbpm.org/learn/gettingStarted.html

If you need to start Workbench on Tomcat, you should use 6.x (which is not supported any more).